# Chrome canvas rendering speed bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

Okay, so I'm running into a weird issue with a game I'm developing all of the sudden, I'm just wondering if anyone has seen something like this before:

- When my window is sized below ~600,000 pixels, it runs *very* smooth.  This is a profile taken at `989x610px`:

[image]

- When my windows is sized a little bit up from that, it slows to a halt, using 99% CPU and running at like 7fps.  This was taken at `990x610px` (1px wider):

[image]

The `990` isn't hard-coded anywhere, because the exact width that it slows down at is dependent on the height, it's more of a "total pixels" thing.

Anyway, I'm just wondering if anyone has seen this before, if it's a known issue, or if I should be filing a bug report with the chrome team.

Comment: maybe your GPU has a maximum texture size? See http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Comment: @WulfSolter - It's possible that it's something like that, but I don't see why that would cause a >200x slow-down?

Comment: No, the change you are seeing is pretty drastic.. I've run in to performance changes of similar magnitudes in the past working on HLSL graphics shaders, but webkit seems to be quite flexible. There are a few walls when you break the {1024, 2048, 4096} ^2 texture sizes, but nothing as extreme as you're seeing. Replicable results on other hardware?

Answer (score 0):

When your **window** is that size or when your **canvas** is that size?

Either way I'm guessing its merely a Chrome bug and you should file a bug report. You should also test to see if its working on Chrome Canary.

There have been similar bugs in the past, such as this still-not-fixed bugs in Chrome for Android where the canvas has distinct functionality above and below 64k total pixels (see bugs [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231916) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242565))